# Using a CSV File to Drive Custom Macro

Tags: macros, expl3, csv, xstring

### Background

I am trying to figure out why the attached MWE is not working. My custom macro `reqUser` works correctly when using the `xstring` both inside and outside of the `csvsimple` environment. The `expl3` only works when it is outside of the `csvsimple` command. I cannot figure out what I have not done correctly.

I am creating a template for future use by my university. The intent with this specific item is to give the future students working on a extremely large document a much easier way of specifying the engineering requirements. Before this macro was made, each item was hand coded into a macro and then copied over to create the list of requirements. It was pretty messy and extremely hard to follow.

### Problem

What is happening within the `expl3` coding?

- `\checkboxYesNoOld`, inside `\reqUserXstring`, works correctly inside `\csvreader`.
- `\checkboxYesNo`, inside `\reqUserExpl`, does not work correctly inside `\csvreader`.

Is using `csvsimple` the "best" way for a CSV driven macro series of commands?

- `etoolbox`, `mathtools`, and`pgfplots` are loaded as well

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 


\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
id,name,description,remarks,parent,verification
M-01, Req Name 1, {A description with numbers and units: \qty{50}{\m}}, {Some remarks with an angle \ang{;;1}} ,-,tir
M-02, Req Name 2, A short description, Some remarks, The Parent Requirement, ai
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\checkboxBox}[1]
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, line width=1.0pt]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.5ex, 1.5ex) #1;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\newcommand{\checkYes}{%
  \checkboxBox
    {%
      ( 0.3ex,  0.3ex) -- +
      ( 0.9ex,  0.9ex)
      ( 0.3ex,  1.2ex) -- + 
      ( 0.9ex, -0.9ex)
    }%
}

% Creates Unchecked Checkbox
\newcommand{\checkNo}{\checkboxBox{}}

% Macro to decide if a checked or unchecked box is needed
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn {ee} { TF, T, F }
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkboxYesNo}{mm}
  {
    \str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
      {\checkYes}
      {\checkNo}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\checkboxYesNoOld}[2]{
  %% #1--Find This;  #2--Search This List
  %% Outputs a Checked or Unchecked box 
  \lowercase{\def\myList{#2}}%
  \lowercase{\def\findMe{#1}}%
  \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{\checkYes}{\checkNo}%
  % \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{Yes \findMe - \myList}{No \findMe - \myList}%
}

% * EXAMPLE OF HOW TO USE THIS COMMAND BELOW
% \reqUser{Req Name}    % Req Name
%     {Req ID}          % Req ID
%     {Wording}         % Wording
%     {Remarks}         % Remarks
%     {Parent}          % Parent
%     {t a i r}         % Verification - Test(t), Analysis(a), Insp(i), Review(r)
\newcommand{\reqUserXstring}[6]{% 
  \begin{tblr}{
    width    =  0.99\textwidth, 
    colspec  =  {>{\small}h{60pt}  X}
    }

    \toprule
    \textbf{Req Name} & \textbf{#2} \\

    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Req ID       &  #1 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Requirement  &  #3 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Remarks      &  #4 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Parent       &  #5 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}

    Verification &
      \small
      \checkboxYesNoOld{t}{#6} Test \hfill
      \checkboxYesNoOld{a}{#6} Analysis \hfill
      \checkboxYesNoOld{i}{#6} Inspection \hfill
      \checkboxYesNoOld{r}{#6} Review-of-Design \\

    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
}

\newcommand{\reqUserExpl}[6]{% 
  \begin{tblr}{
    width    =  0.99\textwidth, 
    colspec  =  {>{\small}h{60pt}  X}
    }

    \toprule
    \textbf{Req Name} & \textbf{#2} \\

    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Req ID       &  #1 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Requirement  &  #3 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Remarks      &  #4 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Parent       &  #5 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}

    Verification &
      \small
      \checkboxYesNo{t}{#6} Test \hfill
      \checkboxYesNo{a}{#6} Analysis \hfill
      \checkboxYesNo{i}{#6} Inspection \hfill
      \checkboxYesNo{r}{#6} Review-of-Design \\

    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
}

\begin{document}

Non-CSV Command:

\reqUserXstring{M-01}{Req Name 1}{A description with numbers and units: \qty{50}{\m}}{Some remarks with an angle \ang{;;1}}{-}{tir}
\reqUserExpl{M-02}{Req Name 2}{A short description}{Some remarks}{The Parent Requirement}{ai}

xstring-CSV Command:

\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{\bigbreak \reqUserXstring{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}{\parent}{\verf}}

expl3-CSV Command:

\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{\bigbreak \reqUserExpl{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}{\parent}{\verf}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah never mind, I just need siunitx v3 to compile it...

Comment: Probably some expansion issue. To start, you probably want to use `NewDocumentCommand` exclusively as it defines protected commands (in this case the definitions are unexpandable anyway, unlike `\newcommand`.

Comment: Ah, I see what the issue is. Try to print out the value of `#1` and `#2` received by `checkboxYesNo` to see what the arguments are. (use `\tl_show:n` or some other convenient package)

Comment: In your definition of `\checkboxYesNo` you find the line 
`\str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }`. My guess is that `\str_if_in:eeTF` triggers expansion of `\str_foldcase:n` before `#1` and `#2` is expanded, thus case-folding and stringification is applied to the control-word-token `\verf` instead of the tokens that form its expansion. Probably this can be solved via `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_foldcase:n { e }` and using `\str_foldcase:e` instead of `\str_foldcase:n`. This is just a guess - currently I cannot test.

Comment: Or within the definition of `\checkboxYesNo` try `\str_if_in:eeTF { \exp_args:Ne \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \exp_args:Ne  \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }`

Comment: Ulrich Diez, can you make the `\exp_args:Ne` into an answer so I can award you the credit, please? The `\exp_args:Ne` worked correctly.

Comment: @Nebabon I just wrote an answer exhibiting some expansion-trickery. There may be better/more intriguing approaches - I am not all too familiar with expl3-expansion-trickery yet. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of `\checkboxYesNo` you find the line
`\str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }`.

My guess is that `\str_if_in:eeTF` triggers expansion of `\str_foldcase:n` before `#1` and `#2` is expanded, thus case-folding and stringification is applied to the control-word-token `\verf` instead of the tokens that form its expansion.

If my guess is right, then probably this can be solved via
`\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_foldcase:n { e }` and using `\str_foldcase:e` instead of `\str_foldcase:n`.

Or within the definition of `\checkboxYesNo` try
`\str_if_in:eeTF { \exp_args:Ne \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \exp_args:Ne  \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }`.

This way `e`-expansion with `\str_if_in:eeTF`'s `e`-type-arguments before triggering expansion of `\str_foldcase:n` triggers expansion of `\exp_args:Ne` which in turn triggers `e`-expansion of `\exp_args:Ne`'s `e`-type argument. The result of `e`-expanding `\exp_args:Ne`'s `e`-type argument in turn will be `\str_foldcase:n`'s argument when it comes to carrying out `\str_foldcase:n`.

If you don't like total expansion/full evaluation of `#1`/`#2` maybe—instead of the tricks presented above—something like

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{%
  \bigbreak 
  \exp_args:Nno \use:n 
                {\reqUserExpl{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}{\parent}}%
                {\verf}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

, where `\reqUserExpl`'s sixth argument will be the toplevel-expansion of the first token of `\exp_args:Nno`'s `o`-type-argument `{\verf}`, i.e., the toplevel-expansion of `\verf`,

instead of

```latex
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{\bigbreak \reqUserExpl{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}{\parent}{\verf}}
```

does the trick.

In order to obtain the toplevel-expansion of the first token of other arguments of `\reqUserExpl` as well, the `\exp_args:Nno \use:n{...}{⟨stuff whose first token shall be expanded once⟩}`-trick can be applied repeatedly within the argument of `\use:n`—with the following code-snippet-example you get toplevel-expansion of `\verf` and of `\parent`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{
  \bigbreak 
  \exp_args:Nno \use:n 
                {
                   \exp_args:Nno \use:n
                   {\reqUserExpl{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}}
                   {\parent}
                }
                {\verf}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If you like it less cumbersome you can combine `\exp:args:Ne` with `\exp_not:o`. Expressed in sloppy terms: In the following you get toplevel-expansion of the first token with all arguments of `\reqUserExpl`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{%
  \bigbreak 
  \exp_args:Ne  \use:n {
                         \exp_not:n{\reqUserExpl}
                         {  \exp_not:o{\idNum}  }
                         {  \exp_not:o{\idName}  }
                         {  \exp_not:o{\desc}  }
                         {  \exp_not:o{\remarks}  }
                         {  \exp_not:o{\parent}  }
                         {  \exp_not:o{\verf}  }
                       }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

You probably can also use `\exp_last_unbraced:Ne`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{%
  \bigbreak 
  \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \reqUserExpl 
                        {
                           {  \exp_not:o{\idNum}  }
                           {  \exp_not:o{\idName}  }
                           {  \exp_not:o{\desc}  }
                           {  \exp_not:o{\remarks}  }
                           {  \exp_not:o{\parent}  }
                           {  \exp_not:o{\verf}  }
                        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If you don't like/are not familiar with expl3-tools for expansion-control and for some reason prefer to stick to more traditional means of expansion-trickery you can have TeX exchange/pass on macro arguments after expanding the first token of the first argument. In the following code-example-snippet `\reqUserExpl`'s sixth argument will be the toplevel-expansion of `\verf`:

```latex
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{%
  \bigbreak
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\verf}{%
    \reqUserExpl{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}{\parent}%
  }%
}
```

This trick can be applied repeatedly, within the second one of the arguments to exchange/to pass on. In the following code-example-snippet `\reqUserExpl`'s sixth argument will be the toplevel-expansion of `\verf` and  `\reqUserExpl`'s fifth argument will be the toplevel-expansion of `\parent`:

```latex
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\csvreader[]{data.csv}
{1=\idNum,2=\idName,3=\desc,4=\remarks,5=\parent,6=\verf}
{%
  \bigbreak
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\verf}{%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\parent}{%
      \reqUserExpl{\idNum }{\idName}{\desc}{\remarks}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your items did the trick.